# Error sending Ajax Request to Django site from non-Django site

Tags: ajax, django

I am currently using Django 1.2. I am trying to send an ajax request to my Django site from our newly established drupal installation. I am able to send the request no problem from one view to another on my DJANGO site but I am unable to send a request from my local machine. I continue to get an error, I assume there is a CSRF verification issue. Does anyone know how I may resolve this issue.

-Greg

Answer (score 0):

Not so recommended but quickest:

You can easily disable csrf protection for certain django views using **csrf_exempt** decorator. You can find more info in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#unprotected-view-needs-the-csrf-token)

this might be also more justified if you run your app in 'trusted environment'.

Please mind that this causes some security problems. If you decide to use csrf_exempt you can think of some additional verifications (eg. you can allow requests on some view for some limited set of IPs or something else).